# max_vertices usage GLSL(opengl)

Tags: performance, 3d, glsl, opengl-3

I'm curious if glsl makes any use of max_vertices in output of glsl geometry shader.
The only thing i realized is that opengl allocates memory for vertices dynamically. 
Does max_vertises exert any influence on performance?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "max_vertices", because last time I checked, OpenGL doesn't have a maximum vertex count.

Comment: @Vallentin sure. [wiki about geometry shaders](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader) just ctrl+f for max_vertices

Comment: Also it turned out, that despite of max_vertices value i can't emit more than 256 vertices for line_strip output type per one shader launch. (graphics card is GeForce GT 630M)

Comment: Actually, the real difference between the geometry shader stage and other stages is that it writes a variable number of vertices at run-time. It is harder to parallelize than other stages as a result and this is one place where performance woes stem from. You are right though, due to limitations on the maximum number of vertices you can emit in a single execution, GS were designed with multiple invocations in mind; they help tremendously with multi-layered rendering as well.